# Filter list top 5000

Tags: list, filter, list-view-threshold

In order to prevent a list view threshold issue I would like to have a list filtered by the last 5000 records. It would be something like Select Top 5000 order by ID Descending. Tried to implement a filter level like below but apparently only accepts [Me] and [Today] as dynamic fields. Any suggestions to achieve this?

[image]

Your support is really appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to filter, I would sort ID in descending order in the view settings and also make it an indexed column. You'll need to select as a column to display in your view, however, for the index to work for you.

Cheers,

-Drew